# Angular Keycloak setup not working in Microsoft Edge (Third party Cookies)

Tags: angular, authentication, cookies, keycloak, microsoft-edge

I have a very weird problem with an angular application that uses keycloak for authentication.

When using Edge, direct-links and page refresh always redirect to the main site of the app. But a direct link when already on the main site works.

E.g.

- current page: mydomain/#/home -> enter url directly -> mydomain/#/sales [works]
- current page: mydomain/#/sales -> refresh [redirect to  mydomain/#/home]
- current page: mydomain/#/sales -> enter url directly -> mydomain/#/sales [redirect to  mydomain/#/home]

Now this happens only in Edge. In all other browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Brave) it works fine.
The only thing that I could find out is that Edge shows a cookie warning. I think it cannot authenticate against keycloak and then keycloak redirects to the main page.

What makes it even more weird is that this happens only when deployed to test or prod environment.
When I run it locally, everything works even in Edge.

Keycloak is running in docker. When deployed the angular app is also running in docker, locally the angular app runs on port 4200 without docker.

[image]

This is the realm security config in keycloak.

[image]

And this is the keycloak angular module initialization

[image]

Unfortunately this is for an internal company project and the we are heavily using Edge, so a browser change is not possible.

- angular: 15.2.2
- keycloak-angular: 13.1.0
- keycloak-js: 20.0.5
- keycloak: 20.0.5
- Edge: 113.0.1774.57

[Edit]
I think the problem is thrid party cookie protection. Couldnt figure out a JS config that is working though. Problem also occurs on Safari (only tested on IPhone)

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_modern_browsers

Comment: Could you please check if third party cookies are blocked in Edge? You can navigate to *edge://settings/content/cookies* and check how you configure this setting: **Block third-party cookies**.